# How to complete an offline installation of RAD Studio (10.4.2 ), when the internet connection(being online) is available?

Tags: rad-studio

After RAD-(Studio 10.4.2/C++ Builder) Offline installation, I have found missing Android SDK Revision(25.2. 5) Tools, through the (SDK Manager). Now the internet connection is available, how can I install the missing Android SDK Revision(25.2. 5) Tools through RAD Studio 10.4.2, so it will be placed in its expected locations as shown in the (SDK Manager) in the included image (Android SDK 25.2.5 (32 & 64)-Bit.png).
the difficulty is that I don't know should I install the SDK independently, and if so, how to make the missing files located where it's expected in RAD Studio, or if there is a way to install the missing tools directly through RAD Studio itself, so every thing should be configured correctly and in its right place.
Hence in both cases I don't know which is applicable, and if both are applicable could you please show me how to accomplish the second one (Through RAD Studio itself), and have a look at the
accompanying image (Android SDK 25.2.5 (32 & 64)-Bit.png).
Tha[image: Android SDK 25.2.5 (32 & 64)-Bit.png]nks very much.

I didn't try any thing because this is the first time for me to develop through such development environment and such platform, hence I don't want to spoil any thing and restart the whole thing again and again,
where (asking) for knowledge is better than (trying) with no knowledge.
Tanks very much